# No POST/create form in DRF Browsable API?

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework (Django version=4.0.4, I know I need to upgrade, but I'm still learning the ropes and djangorestframework~=3.14.0) and Viewsets for an API, but I can't get the Browsable API POST form to show up on the list page. I can see the list of ParameterKeys (so I think urls.py and serializers.py are correct) and I'm using a superuser account so I don't think it's a permissions thing. What's wrong with my setup? I did notice that the Brave browser Agent request has 'text/html' and some 'application/xml', but no 'application/json'...not sure if that's it?

Here is the relevant portion of the model:

```
class ParameterKey(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='parameter_keys')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is the relevant portion of urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import api_views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', api_views.ParameterViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Here is the relevant portion of api_views.py:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, parsers
from .models import ParameterValue, ParameterKey
from .serializers import ParameterValueSerializer, ParameterKeySerializer
from parameters.permissions import IsOwnerOrPublic
# from django.http import JsonResponse
# from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

class ParameterKeyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = ParameterKey.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ParameterKeySerializer
```

Here is the main project urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from datasets.views import DatasetListView, DatasetDetailView
from datasets.api_views import DatasetViewSet
from parameters.api_views import ParameterViewSet
from rest_framework import routers
from files import views
from files.views import upload_file

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
# router.register(r'datasets', DatasetViewSet, basename='dataset')
router.register(r'datasets', DatasetViewSet, basename='dataset')
router.register(r'parameterkeys', ParameterViewSet, basename='parameterkey')  # Add this line


urlpatterns = [
    # Django admin
    path("anything-but-admin/", admin.site.urls),
    # User management
    path("accounts/", include("allauth.urls")),
    # Include URLs from the datasets app
    path("api/v1/datasets/", include("datasets.api_urls")),
    # Include URLs from the parameters app
    path("api/v1/parameters/", include("parameters.urls")),
    # Non-API view
    path("", include("datasets.urls")),
    # API views
    path("api/v1/", include(router.urls)),
    # API authentication
    path("api-auth/", include("rest_framework.urls")),
    path("api/v1/dj-rest-auth/", include("dj_rest_auth.urls")),
    path("api/v1/dj-rest-auth/registration/", include("dj_rest_auth.registration.urls")),
    path('upload/', upload_file, name='upload_file'),
] + static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
)



if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar

    urlpatterns = [
        path("__debug__/", include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
```

Here is the relevant portion of serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import ParameterValue, ParameterKey

class ParameterKeySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ParameterKey
        fields = '__all__'
```

I didn't post my settings.py because SO flagged this as spam. Here are the installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",  # new
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    # Third-party
    "rest_framework",
    "crispy_forms",
    "crispy_bootstrap5",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "debug_toolbar",
    "corsheaders",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "dj_rest_auth", 
    "storages",
    # Local
    "accounts.apps.AccountsConfig",
    'datasets',
    'parameters',
    'files',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",  # new
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",
]
```

And here is the REST_FRAMEWORK settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly",  # new
    ],
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [  # new
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
    ],
        'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],
}
```

I've tried changing permissions and different browsers, and I tried temporarily disabling corsheaders. I believe the problem is in a setting somewhere because I don't get the POST form in the Browsable API for any of my apps. I did have the correct form on a different app when I wrote my own view (ie before I switched to viewsets).

Answer (score 0):

Update: I figured it out. It was a permission thing. I removed the permission_classes= statement and the form now appears.